# PHP5 and smarty configuration problems

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I was reading Beginning PHP and MySQL ecommerce. The author asks to download latest smarty version.When book was published it was smarty 2.x now its 3.x.
I copied all the files from code download to my folder. The error i got was

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'PHP5 requires you to call __construct() instead of Smarty()'
```

To correct it i changed my code to

```
<?php
    // Reference Smarty library
    require_once SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php';

    /* Class that extends Smarty, used to process and display Smarty files */
    class Application extends Smarty
    {
       // Class constructor
       public function __construct()
       {
         // Call Smarty's constructor
         parent::__construct();

         // Change the default template directories
         $this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_DIR;
         $this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
         $this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
      }
    }
 ?>
```

I've follow the following links 
[Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException'](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=80463&sid=68b642cb02f07b03606ebbc3b7d32da8)

**Then I got this error:**

> ERRNO: 2 TEXT: filemtime(): stat failed for
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop/presentation/templates_c\b34e4db7de306d57170626b504196f0c5fe34fa4.file.store_front.tpl.php
>   LOCATION:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_resource.php,
>   line 772, at August 22, 2014, 9:59 am Showing backtrace:
>   filemtime("C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop/presentation/templates_c\b34e4db7de30...")
>   line  772, file: C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_resource.php
>   Smarty_Template_Source.getCompiled(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) #
>   line  699, file:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php
>   Smarty_Internal_Template.__get("compiled") # line  154, file:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase.fetch("store_front.tpl", null, null,
>   null, true) # line  394, file:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase.display("store_front.tpl") # line   16,
>   file: C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop\index.php

Comment: What have you done in your smarty template ? I don't see any problem with this code (just that you should use setter).

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code looks fine.

You should clear your compiled templates directory, check your directory/files permissions and if it doesn't help, in fact you shouldn't care. Those warnings are because of some file system operations optimization.

If you want to turn them off you can use:

```
$this->muteExpectedErrors();
```

inside your constructor (probably after calling parent constructor). [Documentation on muteExpectedErrors](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.mute.expected.errors.tpl)